# Travelling with three little ones without a car

Tags: transport

My wife and I have two children - a three-year-old and a 20-month old, and are expecting a third one soon.

Neither of us drive and we have never owned a car. We rely much on public transport. We are wondering, however, whether it would be manageable after the arrival of our third child. Would really like to hear from those who have been or are in similar situation.

Comment: Are you asking if taking the bus is harder with 3 kids vs 2? I suppose it is...roughly 50% harder. I imagine the biggest hurdle would be going as a solo parent. Lots of 2-child strollers. Not many 3-child ones.

Comment: That would be a most relevant scenario I had in mind indeed. Mind to share your experience?

Comment: It completely depends on where you live...

Comment: We live in England at the moment. I think @DA01 summed our worries well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We did this for a while. It highly depends on the public infrastructure that you have available. Easier in Europe than most US cities.

Somethings that worked

1. Twin stroller, we had one with front and rear seats
2. Bicycle trailer (pulled by hand, not by bike). Groceries in the trailer, kids riding on top, sometimes tied to the handle. They can take turns.
3. Steps are the enemy. Anything that has wheelchair accommodations works great. Any public transportation with "level access" is good. In our case subway & trains was level access. Busses were not (urgh)
4. One adult can wheel two kids, number 3 will have to walk, although they can take turns. Plan your trips accordingly.
5. We looked at the "leash" but it just felt too weird. You need to make sure that the "walker" can follow emergency commands. Practice this in the non-emergency case !!!
6. Network. Friends with a mini-van are good friends :-).
7. Zip-car, rental, taxi are fallback position. Budget for it.
8. Accept and expect the occasional melt down and getting stuck. Don't hesitate to call in spouse, friends, or neighbors if there is one with a bloody knee, one with a poopy diaper and one who just screams on principal at the same time.
9. Routine and repetition helps. When the kids know what's going to happen and what's expected of them, things work out pretty well.
10. It's all entirely doable: We actually managed a trip to Africa with a 1.5 a 2.5 year old in tow. As it turns out number three was already on the way, we just didn't know it a the time :-)

Comment: Don't forget the strollers with the standing platform: http://imgur.com/ea6MEP7

Comment: @philshem At least here in Germany, you can get a "buggy board" or "kiddie board". It's a platform that attaches to the rear axle of any stroller, similar to the thing integrated into the stroller you linked to.

Comment: The leash WILL attract some strange expressions, but, I couldn't care less when I was out and about with my three. With two people, it's not nearly as difficult as when I was solo.

Answer (score 5):

This would be one of those situations where I'd suggest the use of a wraparound sling (like the [Kari-Me](http://www.kari-me.com)) as an addition to your existing double-buggy.  That way you can carry the youngest one comfortably initially and later when the eldest is walking more and further it is small and light enough to keep with you for when they get tired (or just need strapping in) and you can carry the youngest while the big one goes in the buggy.

Even if you only use it for 18 months (and it's good for up to 3yr olds) the eldest will be heading for 5 and be quite happy either walking or with a buggy-board and means you don't have to buy a new buggy!